# Azure Devops Online: Change WIT Definition not supported?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Can someone confirm that changing a Work Item Type (WIT) definition is not possible in Azure Devops Online?
I have tried comparing On-premises vs Hosted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/customize-work?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops)

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. What issue are you running into? Also: this isn't really a programming question.

Comment: Azure DevOps uses a different process model than older on-prem TFS (prior to version 2019 or so). It's possible to change work items, but not via the same mechanisms you may be used to. You need to post a more detailed question to receive more information.

Comment: Ok, here it goes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/change-workflow-wit?view=azure-devops-2019#update-the-xml-definition-for-a-wit

Comment: @Melvin Refer to the top of the page: *This article applies to project customization for Hosted XML and On-premises XML process models.*. You will note that there is a link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/customize-work?view=azure-devops) that has a summary of the different process models and how to customize them.

Comment: Thanks, mate! Will check this out

Comment: @Melvin Hi friend, any update for this issue? Looks like Daniel's comment gives a good direction, does this issue still block you? If the issue persists, feel free to let us know :)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT 
Main issue: 
Need to restrict which user gets to perform certain transitions in a work flow. From what I have understood this can only be done in the WIT Definition's XML file (<TRANSITION>...<FOR...><NOT></TRANSITION>) via the WITADMIN tool, and is only available for the On-premise process model.

Second issue:
Not sure how I identify what AZure Devops Subscription I have. (suspect it is inheritance model, not Hosted XML nor On-premise)

Comment: @Melvin For the first issue, there's one discussion about it [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365830/allow-specifying-state-transitions-when-using-inhe.html). For now, the `TRANSITION` option in not available for inherited process. And according to the [news](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/822993/view.html) from the product team, this would be available in the first half of 2020. Sorry for the inconvenience...

Comment: @Melvin For your second issue, maybe you're trying to check the Access level in `Organization Settings=>Users` ?

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone confirm that changing a Work Item Type (WIT) definition is
>   not possible in Azure Devops Online?

We can't change the WIT in hosted templates like Basic,Agile...processes. But we can create inherited process from `Basic,Agile...` and change the WIT in them(inherited ones).

In Azure Devops Service(online), we can navigate to `Process` related settings in `Organzation Settings=>Boards=>Process`, there exists several hosted templates like `Basic, Agile,Scrum`...

If current organization is created in Service online, these WITs in those hosted processes can not be modified. See:

[image]

We need to right-click `...` and choose `create inherited process` and the inherited process is something we can use to change WIT, see:

[image]

[image]

In addition: If your current organization is migrated from tfs's collection, you can change the WIT by modifying the xml.

Comment: Thanks, Lance.
I already have an inherited process, but what I am trying to (restrict transitions between states) is not available for me (as per my comment above).
Thank you very much for your help so far :) appreciate it

Comment: @Melvin Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? If it persists to block you or you're still confused with something please feel free to let me know :)